# Cannot implicitly convert "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader" to "SqlDataReader.SqlDataReader"

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ado.net

I am new to C#. Just following Kudvenkat tutorials for beginners. I get an error on this line:

```
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Something to do with `ExecuteReader();`

I am sure its something simple, but could you please explain why does it happens?

My aspx.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SqlDataReader
{
    public partial class SqlDataReader : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // creating variable that holds value of connection string 
            string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

            // creating connection object with use of "using" block
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                con.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 5 ProductID, LocationID,Shelf,Quantity from [Production].[ProductInventory]", con);

                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();   // --Error

                GridView1.DataSource = rdr;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SqlDataReader.aspx.cs" Inherits="SqlDataReader.SqlDataReader" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2">
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to name your class (and also namespace) to other name, your class name `SqlDataReader` just the same as the official one, which C# don't know which you are using

Comment: Or you could just do: `var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();` or better: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();`. Of course the best practice is to rename your namespace as @Prisoner suggests.

Comment: Great. Thank you guys !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because of the name of your class and the namespace, the compiler assumes that `rdr` is of type `SqlDataReader` which is your class name under namespace `SqlDataReader`. So the best option here is **Rename your class**, Alternative option also for you is *fully qualified names*. which means you have to specify the namespace of the class as well while instantiating the class, ie., the code will be like this:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // No Error now
```

Another option for you is make use of static type definer, `var` by using this type will be automatically assigned to store the value that we are assiging to them, that is :

```
var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // No Error now
```

Here `rdr` will be of type what `ExecuteReader()` method is returing.

Comment: @Oleg: Happy to help you